# How do I add an OR expression between two ->addExpression() in Drupal 7

Tags: database

I am trying to return flagged content that is either flagged as a favorite or flagged as visited. I can get them to return but i believe Drupal is doing an **and** between the 2 `addExpression()` in the query because it is only showing results if either both are flagged. Not one or the other.Here is my code. This is being used for the Drupal Services module to return some values. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$query->leftJoin('flag_content', 'flag', "n.nid = flag.content_id AND flag.uid = $user->uid");
$query->addExpression("flag.fid is not null AND flag.fid = 2", "is_flagged");
$query->addExpression("flag.fid is not null AND flag.fid = 3", "is_visited");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`addExpression()` is for adding expressions to the query, (i.e. fields that will be selected), you can't use it to add conditions.

You could either use a combination of [`db_and()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_and/7) and [`db_or()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_or/7) to build up your conditions, or (and probably easier) just use the `where()` method instead:

```
$condition = '(flag.fid is not null AND flag.fid = :fid1) OR (flag.fid is not null AND flag.fid = :fid2)';
$query->where($condition, array(':fid1' => 2, ':fid2' => 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing to get my results needed. If anyone can tell me if there is a better way I would love to hear. I guess it wasn't adding an and but it was returning a record for each item in the join. Sorry my sql skills need some work.

```
$query->leftJoin('flag_content', 'flag', "flag.fid = 2 AND n.nid = flag.content_id AND flag.uid = $user->uid");
$query->leftJoin('flag_content', 'visited', "visited.fid = 3 AND n.nid = visited.content_id AND visited.uid = $user->uid");
$query->addExpression("flag.fid is not null", "is_flagged");
$query->addExpression("visited.fid is not null", "is_visited");
```

Comment: Please see the answer above, `addExpression` isn't for adding conditions. The two calls to `addExpression` you've got there will have zero effect except to add more selected fields to the query. Try removing them from your query and you'll see that nothing changes